# A gcc compilation error asking -fPIE option

Tags: command-line, compiling, gcc

I have downloaded a zip file from the following link by clicking code then Download
ZIP.
https://github.com/b/LatticeCrypto
Then I decompressed it and open the terminal in the folder ~/Desktop/LatticeCrypto-master.
After reading README.txt, I have run the following command on my terminal.

```
make CC=gcc ARCH=x64 ASM=TRUE AVX2=TRUE
```

It gives the following message.

```
gcc -c -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  tests/tests.c
gcc -c -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  tests/test_extras.c
gcc -c -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  kex.c
gcc -c -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  random.c
gcc -c -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  ntt_constants.c
gcc -c -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  AMD64/ntt_x64_asm.S
gcc -c -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  AMD64/error_asm.S
gcc -c -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  AMD64/ntt_x64.c
gcc -c -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  AMD64/consts.c
gcc -o test tests.o test_extras.o kex.o random.o ntt_constants.o ntt_x64_asm.o error_asm.o ntt_x64.o consts.o 
/usr/bin/ld: ntt_x64_asm.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `MASK12x8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: error_asm.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `ONE32x' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:57: test] Error 1
```

In order to resolve the error, I have added the -fPIE option in line 42 and after that, I have added $(CFLAGS) in line 57 of the makefile which is present in the decompressed file. Then I have run the command "make CC=gcc ARCH=x64 ASM=TRUE AVX2=TRUE". It prints the following message.

```
gcc -c -fPIE -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  tests/tests.c
gcc -c -fPIE -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  tests/test_extras.c
gcc -c -fPIE -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  kex.c
gcc -c -fPIE -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  random.c
gcc -c -fPIE -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  ntt_constants.c
gcc -c -fPIE -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  AMD64/ntt_x64_asm.S
gcc -c -fPIE -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  AMD64/error_asm.S
gcc -c -fPIE -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  AMD64/ntt_x64.c
gcc -c -fPIE -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_  AMD64/consts.c
gcc -o test tests.o test_extras.o kex.o random.o ntt_constants.o ntt_x64_asm.o error_asm.o ntt_x64.o consts.o  -c -fPIE -O3       -mavx2 -D _AMD64_ -D __LINUX__ -D _AVX2_ -D _ASM_ 
gcc: warning: tests.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: test_extras.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: kex.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: random.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: ntt_constants.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: ntt_x64_asm.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: error_asm.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: ntt_x64.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: consts.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

After successful compilation, it should generate an object file named test which we need
to run. But it is not creating that file. Please help in this regard.

Comment: From the man page for gcc, "the -c option says not to run the linker.", and you have the -c option on the line which would link the test file.

Comment: I have modified line 57 of makefile. Removed -c option then it gives the following error.

Comment: I have added another variable named LFLAGS=CFLAGS (excludes -c option) in the makefile. Added $(LFLAGS) in line 57 of the makefile. Then I have run the "make CC=gcc ARCH=x64 ASM=TRUE AVX2=TRUE". It gives the first error which I have mentioned in my post.